# Struts2 : Customize s:textfield tag

Tags: struts2, tags, customization

I want to customize struts2  tag.

In my web app some of the fields are mandatory.So I want to customize struts2 text filed in such a way that It will display text box and a "*" symbol(mandatory sign) combined.

So I dont need to hard code "*" after each mandatory text field.

One thing is that I have not used strtus2 built in theme. So I dont want to enable the theme to implement this functionality.

Then .. How can I implement such a customized text field ?

Thanx,
Gunjan Shah.

Comment: You need to use a theme, or a custom tag or perhaps the struts2 component tag (I have not looked at that in some time so I might be wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an attribute named "required". You can set it to true. It will set * (red colored) symbol after the label.

Its built in facility provieded by struts.

Comment: -1. REASON : required=true provides <span class="required">*</span> NOT just a * with red color. You need to override the style with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use mandatoru="true" in s: tags. This will by default place the * sign before that field.

Hope this helps.